# How can I set up my application to ONLY return messages for ResponseStatusException?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

By default, Spring Boot does not return messages for any exceptions, including `ResponseStatusException`, meaning that the message about `bar` below will not be returned to the client:

```java
    @GetMapping("/foo")
    @ResponseBody
    public Foo getFoo(@RequestParam(name = "bar", defaultValue = "0") int bar) {
        if (bar <= 0) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "bar must always be positive");
        }
        return example.getFoo(bar);
    }
```

This can be changed by setting `server.error.include-message=always` in the `application.properties`, however this causes ALL exception messages to be returned to the client, including this one:

```java
    @GetMapping("/baz")
    @ResponseBody
    public Baz getBaz() {
        if (!security.checkSecurity()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Security breach! Hope no one finds out!");
        }
        return example.getBaz();
    }
```

I know this is a trivial example and the solution would be just "don't throw server exceptions from your controller", but the exception might actually come from some other code buried deep in the application, it could even be a `NullPointerException` or whatever.

How can I get the application to show messages only from `ResponseStatusException` and not other types of exception? (I guess other than adding try-catch clauses to every single controller method.)

Comment: Then define your exception which will be handled as you wish. Check one of my previous answers today https://stackoverflow.com/a/67090661/7237884

Comment: @Boug this is similar to Akif's answer. Here you are generating the `ResponseEntity` manually... I want Spring to generate the `ResponseEntity` from my `ResponseStatusException`, otherwise I feel there is no point in using `ResponseStatusException`. Is there a way to just tell Spring to handle `ResponseStatusException` in the default way in your `handleXYZ` methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra (@ExceptionHandler) methods to any controller to specifically handle exceptions thrown by request handling (@RequestMapping) methods in the same controller. Such methods can:

- Handle exceptions without the @ResponseStatus annotation (typically predefined exceptions that you didn’t write)
- Redirect the user to a dedicated error view
- Build a totally custom error response

Controller advice allows you to use exactly the same exception handling techniques but apply them across the **whole application**, not just to an individual controller. You can think of them as an annotation-driven interceptor.

Any class annotated with @ControllerAdvice becomes a controller-advice and three types of method are supported:

- Exception handling methods annotated with @ExceptionHandler.
- Model enhancement methods (for adding additional data to the model) annotated with @ModelAttribute. Note that these attributes are not available to the exception handling views.
- Binder initialization methods (used for configuring form-handling) annotated with
  @InitBinder.

---

Solution:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestControllerAdvice {

  @ExceptionHandler(ResponseStatusException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleStatusException(ResponseStatusException exception) {
    throw exception;
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(Exception exception) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Exception", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }
}
```

Comment: Here you are generating the `ResponseEntity` manually... I want Spring to generate the `ResponseEntity` from my `ResponseStatusException`, otherwise I feel there is no point in using `ResponseStatusException`. Is there a way to just tell Spring to handle `ResponseStatusException` in the default way in your `handleStatusException` method?

Comment: Update answer. Yes, just throw a status exception and you will have default behavior.

Comment: Hmm, that worked, which I was quite surprised about as I always thought exceptions thrown from exception handlers wouldn't get handled. However, is there a way to do it for the default exceptions? I tried `throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Unknown error occurred")` but it didn't work, the original exception's message got returned to the client rather than "Unknown error occurred". The problem with `ResponseEntity` is it requires you to create the error object yourself. For `ResponseStatusException`, Spring automatically creates the error object with 5 fields

Comment: PS: I also found that if ANY exception gets thrown from the exception handler, it will just process the original exception as normal. You don't have to re-throw the exception that was passed in as you did. In other words, Spring ignores the exception thrown from the exception handler, and serializes the originally thrown exception. But in the case of normal exceptions, I want Spring to serialize a new `ResponseStatusException` I'm creating, and NOT the original exception.

Comment: I found a possible solution: `(new DefaultErrorAttributes()).resolveException(request, response, this, new ResponseStatusException(...));` However this returns a message `500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR "Unknown error occurred"` rather than just `Unknown error occurred`

Comment: Also, with this last way, it returns the status code as 400, even if you tell it 500

Answer (score -1):

Catch all the exceptions and in the catch block throw ResponseStatusException like in:

```
@GetMapping("/actor/{id}")
public String getActorName(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    try {
        return actorService.getActor(id);
    } catch (ActorNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(
          HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Actor Not Found", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that's what I was saying in my original post when I said "(I guess other than adding try-catch clauses to every single controller method.)" I'd rather avoid doing this if possible for Runtime Exceptions, as it will cause every controller method to be somewhat polluted with error handling code. For checked exceptions it's fine, as you would have to catch those anyway and it's bad practice to have throws clause in controller methods.